# Python loop not correctly looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

My loop is "supposed" to go through the list from [0] to the final item which is at most [7] and then purchase and count how many times it purchased that item from the list and then multiply the result by a value.

What it is currently doing is purchasing a low number of items, outputting how many times each has been purchased and thats it. It isn't even "spending" all of its "allowance"

https://pastebin.com/vSecjxA5

and it generally outputs

```
CP Total: 2000
Type Item: Item
# of Properties: 5
{'MDEF': 4}
{'SPR': 3}
{'AGI': 2}
{'CRIT': 3}
{}
```

Which if you see the code and add the costs together it only adds up to 100-200 at most not anywhere near 2000

```
for aProp in S:
    cost = CostDic[aProp]
    if (cost * 5) < CP:
        purchase_ls = []
        while CP >= cost:
            b = randint(1, 5)
            cost = cost * b
            if CP < cost:
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            CP = CP - cost
    else:
        purchase_ls = []
        while CP >= cost:
            cost = cost
            if CP < cost:
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            CP = CP - cost
    print(dict(Counter(purchase_ls)))
```

Is the section in particular that is causing me grief

Comment: Could you post the values of `S`, `CostDic` and `CP`??

Comment: `cost = cost` does nothing

Comment: @Anwarvic the values are in the pastebin link i posted with the FULL code of this

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
    while CP >= cost:
        b = randint(1, 5)
        cost = cost * b
        # More stuff follows...
```

In this loop you have now modified the value of `cost`, which I'm guessing you didn't mean to do. Specifically, in the line `cost = cost * b` I believe your intent was that `cost` on the right-hand side is representing the cost of an individual unit, and the `cost` on the left-hand side is representing the cost of "n" units, where "n" is a random number between 1 and 5.

But what this code is actually doing is different from that intention. The second time you enter that `while` loop, the variable `cost` is still at its new, higher value, and then will get multiplied **again** by a random number 1-5. So at this rate `cost` will quickly grow too large for `CP >= cost` to remain true.

I think what tripped you up here is that you used the same variable `cost` to represent different things at different times. I'd strongly suggest you change this into two different variables with more meaningful names, for example `unitCost` and `groupCost`, to prevent this type of confusion in the code later on.

Comment: Okay so I can change the cost = cost * b into mcost = cost * b which sets its own variable up in the loop that will pull from cost which will always be the base value?

Second, i just realized when it appends the list it only adds 1 item, how do i say get it to add multiple items because if b = 5 its supposed to add one of the values to the list 5 times

Comment: Also finally, when it does its purchase against the first stored object in the list S, its "supposed" to move on to the next one in the list and continue purchasing. BUT it just stays on the first object

Comment: @B14d3r11 the simplest way to add `b` items to your list would be to modify your statement `purchase_ls.append(aProp)` to instead read `purchase_ls.extend([aProp] * b)`

Answer (score 0):

For the loop in question, i have now modified it to

```
for aProp in S:
    cost = CostDic[aProp]
    if (cost * 5) < CP:
        purchase_ls = []
        while CP >= cost:
            b = randint(1, 5)
            mcost = cost*b
            if CP < mcost:
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            CP = CP - mcost
    else:
        purchase_ls = []
        while CP >= cost:
            if CP < cost:
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            CP = CP - cost
    print(dict(Counter(purchase_ls)))
```

Which does the looping part fine but it isn't doing 2 things correctly like i had hoped

1. It isn't adding the correct amount of append's to the list cause it is just adding 1 aProp when it is purchased in the top section of the loop it purchases b amount of them.
2. It doesn't cycle through the S list to purchase from. Its supposed to go from [0] to the final one (say it has 5 items) [4] and purchase them b times for each (unless it can only grab one) and then move on to the next one so, [0] rolls 3, gets purchased 3 times and moves to [1] which gets purchased 5 times, then moves on to... and finally hits [4] which gets purchased 2 times and then if it still has leftover CP it goes back through the list from [0]-[4] again.